# Javascript Scope

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <title>Youtube embed test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function onYouTubePlayerReady( playerid )
        {
            ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
        }

        function embedPlayer()
        {
            var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
            var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };
            swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?enablejsapi=1",
                       "ytapiplayer", "1024", "768", "8", null, null, params, atts);
        }

        function loadVideo( id, start )
        {
            ytplayer.loadVideoById( id, start );
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="embedPlayer()">
    <div id="ytapiplayer">
        You need Flash player 8+ and JavaScript enabled to view this video.
    </div>

    <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="loadVideo('bBObeZ6Vj3A',2);">Load</a>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm new to Javascript so I'm having trouble trying to get this to work. The debugger is telling me that ytplayer is undefined in function loadVideo(). Why is this? I understand that the variable declared in onYouTubePlayerReady goes out of scope when the brace ends. So how can I access the loadVideoById method? What confuses me further is that I can do something like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="ytplayer.loadVideoById('e1h5TzdTq0o', 0);">test</a>
```

and it turns out that, that is perfectly legal. But why am I allowed to use ytplayer? I'm assuming it has something to do with the callback function onYouTubePlayerReady?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onYouTubePlayerReady(  )  // playerid is usefull here or not 
{
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
    return ytplayer;
}


function loadVideo( id, start )
{
    ytplayer  = onYouTubePlayerReady();  // call onYouTubePlayerReady to get the object of ytplayer
    ytplayer.loadVideoById( id, start );
}
```